# Windows Update: why installing KB4516115?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I just installed Windwos 10 built 1903. Then, I then went to Settings>Windows Update to download updates.

I found that one of the available update is KB4516115 (Security Update for Adobe Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1903) and it's being downloaded.

I just install Windows and no programs has been installed. I went to Settings>Apps and found no Adobe product.

Do I have to have this update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just installed Windows 10 built 1903. Then, I then went to Settings>Windows Update to download updates.
>   I found that one of the available updates is KB4516115 (Security Update for Adobe Flash Player for Windows 10 Version 1903) and it's being downloaded.

[KB4516115](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4516115) was released on September 9th, 2019.  If it's being installed, then the update was not already installed.  KB516115 superseded [KB4503308](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4503308) which released on June 9th, 2019.

> I just install Windows and no programs have been installed. I went to Settings>Apps and found no Adobe product.

Adobe Flash Player updates on Windows 10 are handled entirely through Windows Update.  Adobe Flash is built-into Microsoft Edge.  Microsoft Edge is installed on all current release versions of Windows 10.

> Do I have to have this update?

If you allowed the update to install, then you do indeed have the update, since the update was applicable to your installation.

Source: [Security update deployment: September 10, 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/20190910/security-update-deployment)